# jQuery list hide/show based on current class

Tags: jquery

I want to display the entire ul li struct that has a class `current` somewhere in it

Every other ul li I want to hide. EXCEPT The top level.

My jQuery is not doing what I want, any suggestions?

```
$("ul li").find("ul").hide();
$("ul:has(li.current)").parents().show();
$("ul:has(li.current)").children().show();
```

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Entire struct is displayed
        <ul>
            <li>1.1
                 <ul>
                     <li class="current">1.1.1</li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li>1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Only this li is shown
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Displays as:

- Entire struct is displayed

  - 1.1

    - 1.1.1
  - 1.2
- Only this li is shown

EDIT: added children to jQuery, but still not working as desired.

Comment: I think you'll need to recurse up the tree to all parents when finding .current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me..

```
$("ul").find("ul").hide();
$("ul > li.current").find("ul").show().end().parents().show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHyPS/5/

Comment: That only displays the ul on the current level. If the `current` class is on the second level, I still need the third level open.

Comment: @kylex I don't exactly know what you mean, was it the lack of indentation on the example?.. it will work at any level, I have updated the example http://jsfiddle.net/uHyPS/1/

Comment: @Quinten if you put the `current` class on the li for BLAH the li's below do not display, and they need to.

Comment: @kylex Okay, my misunderstanding.. Try the new revision, I will update the example. http://jsfiddle.net/uHyPS/5/